# How to drop a box to the mouse position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to learn unity, and made my first own game and stucked at the beginning. The first idea was to drop a box (cube) to the mouse position. There are many videos and posts about getting the mouse position, and i tried to use them. My problem is, the mouse position i got is the camera's position, instead of the plane.
As you can see, it is kinda works, but it isn't fall to the plane.
https://prnt.sc/lmrmcl

My code:

```
     void Update()
{
    Wall();
}

void Wall()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            wall = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            Rigidbody wallsRigidbody = wall.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

            wall.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.6f, 0.6f, 0.6f);
            wallsRigidbody.mass = 1f;
            wallsRigidbody.angularDrag = 0.05f;
            wallsRigidbody.useGravity = true;
            wallsRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;

            wall.transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        }
        Debug.Log(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
        BoxCollider wallsCollider = wall.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
        wallsCollider.size = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

How should i change my code to get the right position?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I'm hoping it'll still get you where you need to go.

Prefabs are your friends! I'd highly recommend leveraging them here instead of constructing a cube directly in code.

But first, make sure everything else is set up right. Go ahead and construct a cube by hand in the Editor and make sure that when you hit Play, it falls as you expect. It should, provided it has a Rigidbody, collider, and you have gravity enabled (true by default).

If that works, drag that cube from your `Hierarchy` view into a folder in the `Project` view. This creates a prefab. You can now delete the cube from the `Hierarchy` view.

Update your script to have a public GameObject field, e.g.

```
public GameObject cubeToCreate;
```

Then, in the Inspector pane for whatever gameobject has that script attached, you should get a new field, "Cube To Create". Drag your prefab cube into that slot.

Lastly...update your code to `wall = Instantiate(cubeToCreate)`. You'll still need to update the position, but you should be able to drop the rest of the initialization logic you have above, e.g. setting mass and drag.

---

As for the actual problem, the first thing that concerns me is how do you plan on turning a 2d mouse click into a 3d point? For the axis going "into" the screen...how should the game determine the value for that?

[Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) accepts a Vector3, but you're passing it a Vector2 (`Input.mousePosition`, which gets converted to a z=0 Vector3), so the point is 0 units from the camera -- so in a plane that intersects with the camera.

I haven't done this, but I think you'll need to do [raycasting](https://answers.unity.com/questions/13577/using-raycast-to-get-mouse-input.html) of some sort. Maybe create an invisible 2d plane with a collider on it, and cast a physics ray from the camera, and wherever it hits that plane, that's the point where you want to create your cube. [This post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2d-raycast-from-mouse-to-screen.211708/) has a couple hints, though it's geared toward 2D. That might all be overkill, too -- if you create a new Vector3 and initialize it with your mouse position, you can set the z coordinate to whatever you want, but then your cube creation will be in terms of distance *from the camera*, which is not the best idea.

Hope this helps.